# Ignore windowSoftInputMode for certain elements eg. Background Image

Tags: android, scrollview, window-soft-input-mode

My question is, is there a way to get a certain view element to ignore the windowSoftInput setting, or to set a specific setting for one view element? (Any other solutions to my problem are also welcome)

Below are more details about my problem.

I have an Android activity with a background image set to the main FrameLayout. This layout contains a few other layouts, among others a brand logo on one side, and a scrollview with edittext boxes on the other side.

Using the `windowSoftInput="adjustResize"` works pretty well, but it distorts the background image. Using `windowSoftInput="adjustPan"` however pans the brand logo out of the screen and messes with the scrollview, and the keyboard blocks the edittext boxes.

So far, looking around the web and the docs I can't find a solution, or if this is even possible. Android layouts always seem to confuse me though..